# How to measure file upload time with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My first approach was to create a `HandlerInterceptor`, save the time in `preHandle` and calculate the elapsed time in my controller after processing the file.

However I am not sure how accurate this measurement is, or if is there a better way?